# Flash and php session sharing?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I have made a website and put inside it a flash game.

For people to play the game they have to log into the website.

Logging to the website will create a session. I want for the flash game to get the session id ,

so I have created a function that gets the session id. It works only in Internet Explorer and

when I tried it in Chrome, it didn't retrieve the session id.

So any help?

I have written a php file that will be used by the as3 to get the session id, the php code is this:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

require('libraries/joomla/factory.php');
class session
{
    public function getId()
    {
        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $mainframe->initialise();

        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
        $user_id = $user->get('id');

        //echo($user_id);

        return $user_id;
    }
}

?>
```

When i tried the flash in IE, the flash got the correct session id, but in Chrome it didn't.

Comment: What is the function? How do you know it is not working in other browsers. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing on the session identifier stored in a cookie to the embedded Flash, and then passing it on with Flash as a parameter to the server to identify and initialise the session.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this about 5 years ago:

http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/117

My final solution was to use an alternative token (not the same as the session cookie, for security). The token would get embedded in the  tag as a flashvar. The flash player would then manually send along this token with every HTTP request.

Lastly, on the server, I would match the token with the real session id, and call session_id()/session_start().